# How to make react-facebook's comments component responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, facebook, responsive

I am using [react-facebook](https://github.com/seeden/react-facebook) to add Facebook comments section to my website:

```
<div className="fb-wrapper">
  <FacebookProvider appId="928199034262053">
    <Like
      href={`samplelink`}
      colorScheme="dark"
      showFaces
      share
    />
    <Comments href={`samplelink`} />
  </FacebookProvider>
</div>
```

But it's wider than screen on mobile devices.
Styling `fb-wrapper` doesn't do any work.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the container of this? And some styling you used for the rest of the app.